# Ionic Stay Logged In

Tags: angular, routes, guard

Look, I have a page in my ionic project that it's a simple login form,where the user enters its CPF, then redirects to a page where it will create a new password or type an existing one.
Which is the problem? I made a simple route guard block the user if it tries to access the `home.page` before login

**auth-login.service.ts**

```js
authenticatedUser: boolean;

private validatedPassword: number;

 validatePassword(user, password) {
      this.http
          .get<RootObject>(
              environment.url + environment.token + '&Metodo=alunoCheckPwd&AlunoIDMain=' + user.id + '&AlunoPwd=' + password
          )
          .subscribe(response => {
              this.validatedPassword = response.LOGIN_SENHA.Password;

              if (this.validatedPassword === 1) {
                  this.loggedIn();

              } else {
                  alert('Invalid Password');
              }
          });
  }

 loggedIn() {
      this.authenticatedUser= true;

      this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');

  }

 userIsAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticatedUser;
 }
```

**auth-guard.ts**

```
      route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    if (this.authLoginService.userIsAuthenticated()) {
      return true;

    } else {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');

    return false;
    }

  }
```

The guard works just fine.

What is the problem? How do i keep this user logged in? Because at this moment, the user has to log in everytime it opens the app.

Answer (score 0):

The loaclStorage API is already available so all you need to do, at the point where it is  convenient to save the information, is this:

```
localStorage.setItem('logged_in', true); // or false
```

And retrieve the value with:

```
localStorage.getItem('logged_in'));
```

Presumably, you'll save this at the point where the password is confirmed and retrieve at some point as the login screen is loading or prior to that.

There are other methods for handling sessions that are better than this but as a simple, easy-to-use method, the above is all there is to it.

Comment: So, i don't need the function `userIsAuthenticated()`? What i did, i went to **auth-guard.ts** and created a variable `private userIsAuthenticated = false;`, then inside the `canActivate()` i put `this.userIsAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')`, in the if same thing `if (this.userIsAuthenticated === true) { return true }`, In the page where the user enters its password, i put `login () { this.authLoginService.validarSenha( this.usuario, this.senha );` and then: `localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true); ` This is right?